# NestJS- How to make sure Azure Keyvault variables are set before starting the AppModule

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, nestjs

I'm running an NestJS application. In that application I load an env file in which some values refer to the Azure Keyvault. One of those values is the password for the Redis cache. I load the Redis cache in using the CacheModule in the AppModule. The problem is that this is initialized before the Azure KeyVault variable is retrieved and set, causing the connection to fail.
How would I tackle this?

I tried setting it using process.env when I retrieve the value, but that didn't work.